# Form validation on multiple textfield using array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im trying to create a dynamic text field where user can press an add button to insert another entry. I also created a javascript code to check whether the user input is available or not ( similar to checking username is available or not).

However, since my form is a dynamic form, the checking part will only checks for the first textfield. If I click add, the second textfield wont be 'validated'. Below is my jsfiddle or my html and javascript code.

UPDATE:

I think the problem lies on the javascript because it only runs on the first default textfield row. If I added a new row and insert a value and check on network on developers tool, my check.php doesnt run. How do I make the javascript code to rerun on every gamecenter[] count?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').on('change', function() {

    var number = $('#number').val();
    var gamecenter = $('#gamecenter').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'check.php',
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        number: number,
        gamecenter: gamecenter
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == '0') {
          $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Number not available</span>');
          $('#proceed').attr("disabled", true);
          $('#number').addClass('validation-error');
        } else {
          $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Number Available</span>');
          $('#proceed').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#number').removeClass('validation-error');
          // $('#number').addClass('validation-success');

        }
      }
    })

  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#number').blur(function() {

    var number = $('#number').val();
    var gamecenter = $('#gamecenter').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'check.php',
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        number: number,
        gamecenter: gamecenter
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == '0') {
          $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Number not available</span>');
          $('#proceed').attr("disabled", true);
          $('#number').addClass('validation-error');
        } else {
          $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Number Available</span>');
          $('#proceed').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#number').removeClass('validation-error');
        }
      }
    })

  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td> <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="number[]" id="number" value="" class="form-control item_name number" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" /><span id="availability"></span></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price"  class="form-control item_quantity price" required autocomplete="off" /></td>';
    html += '<td><select name="gamecenter[]" id="gamecenter" class="form-control item_unit gamecenter" required><option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="Damacai">Damacai</option><option value="Magnum">Magnum</option><option value="Toto">Toto</option></select></td>';
    html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
    $('#item_table').append(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });

  $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var error = '';
    $('.number').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Enter Item Name at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });

    $('.price').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });

    $('.gamecenter').each(function() {
      var count = 1;
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        error += "<p>Select Unit at " + count + " Row</p>";
        return false;
      }
      count = count + 1;
    });

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

    if (error == '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
          $(document.body).append(data);

        }

      });
    } else {
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.box {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

.validation-error {
  border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

.validation-success {
  border: 1px solid #008000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container box">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
    <tr>
      <th>2D Number</th>
      <th>Price (RM)</th>
      <th>Game Center</th>
      <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="number[]" id="number" value="" class="form-control item_name" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" /><span id="availability"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" class="form-control item_quantity" required autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="gamecenter[]" id="gamecenter" class="form-control item_unit" required><option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="Damacai">Damacai</option><option value="Magnum">Magnum</option><option value="Toto">Toto</option></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="proceed" id="proceed" class="btn btn-info" value="Check Number" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

and my Check.php code.

```
   <?php  
   //check.php  
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "2d_system"); 
   if(isset($_POST["number"]) && ($_POST["gamecenter"]))
   {

   $number = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["number"]);
   $gamecenter = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["gamecenter"]);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM number_availability WHERE Number = '".$number."' 
   AND GameCenter = '".$gamecenter."' AND Availability != 0";
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
   }

   ?>
```

Any tips/advice/help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: ids must be unique. you cannot have a form that generates inputs that will all have the same  id. also, please  try to minimize your examples. i for one would prefer not to have to read 100 lines of code just to figure out whats happening in your script. read [how to make an mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Forgive me, ill comply to mcve in the future. So, what exactly are you suggesting? I do not understand.

Comment: between my comment and the answer given by G_S you should have all the info you need. you are creating elements with id's instead of classes. i really don't know how to be more clear without writing the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a class `$('.number')` to check for condition. But you are not adding a class when adding a new row.

HTML file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src='./testjsfile.js'></script>
<form id='insert_form'>
<div class="container box">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
    <tr>
      <th>2D Number</th>
      <th>Price (RM)</th>
      <th>Game Center</th>
      <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number"  name="number[]" id="number" value="" class="form-control item_name" required autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" /><span id="availability"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="price[]" id="price" class="form-control item_quantity"  autocomplete="off" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="gamecenter[]" id="gamecenter" class="form-control item_unit" ><option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="Damacai">Damacai</option><option value="Magnum">Magnum</option><option value="Toto">Toto</option></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <div align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="proceed" id="proceed" class="btn btn-info" value="Check Number" />
  </div>
  <div id='error'></div>
  </form>
```

and JS file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function() {

      var number = $('#number').val();
      var gamecenter = $('#gamecenter').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          number: number,
          gamecenter: gamecenter
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == '0') {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Number not available</span>');
            $('#proceed').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#number').addClass('validation-error');
          } else {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Number Available</span>');
            $('#proceed').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#number').removeClass('validation-error');
            // $('#number').addClass('validation-success');

          }
        }
      })

    });
  });


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#number').blur(function() {

      var number = $('#number').val();
      var gamecenter = $('#gamecenter').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          number: number,
          gamecenter: gamecenter
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == '0') {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-danger">Number not available</span>');
            $('#proceed').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#number').addClass('validation-error');
          } else {
            $('#availability').html('<span class="text-success">Number Available</span>');
            $('#proceed').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#number').removeClass('validation-error');
          }
        }
      })

    });
  });



  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
      var html = '';
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td> <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="number[]" id="number" value="" class="form-control item_name number"  autocomplete="off" maxlength="3" /><span id="availability"></span></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price"  class="form-control item_quantity price" autocomplete="off" /></td>';
      html += '<td><select name="gamecenter[]" id="gamecenter" class="form-control item_unit gamecenter"><option value="">Select Unit</option><option value="Damacai">Damacai</option><option value="Magnum">Magnum</option><option value="Toto">Toto</option></select></td>';
      html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
      $('#item_table').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        debugger
      event.preventDefault();
      var error = '';
      $('.number').each(function() {
        var count = 1;
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          error += "<p>Enter Item Name at " + count + " Row</p>";
          return false;
        }
        count = count + 1;
      });

      $('.price').each(function() {
        var count = 1;
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at " + count + " Row</p>";
          return false;
        }
        count = count + 1;
      });

      $('.gamecenter').each(function() {
        var count = 1;
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          error += "<p>Select Unit at " + count + " Row</p>";
          return false;
        }
        count = count + 1;
      });

      var form_data = $(this).serialize();

      if (error == '') {
        $.ajax({
          url: "insert.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: form_data,
          success: function(data) {
            $(document.body).append(data);

          }

        });
      } else {
        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + error + '</div>');
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by not adding a class when adding a new row?

Comment: in $(document).on('click', ' ..... , looks like you are adding new row. Here you are adding different HTML elements. I hope you should add number class also because you are using .number for checking empty condition

Comment: How do I add the class, on $(document).on('click', '.add', function()? I really do not know the syntax. Im sorry for my lack of understanding/knowledge

Comment: Updated html code.   class="form-control item_name number"  I added a number class as above. Still I am not sure if thats the only issue. Check by adding it

Comment: Ive tried like u suggested, but it still only validate/check the first default row.

Comment: As I said thats not the only issue. Can you please update your code now so that we can check what else is the issue?

Comment: Which browser are you using? You already added 'required' validation and it should be firing if you didnt enter value in text boxes. I just checked it and its working fine

Comment: Im using chrome. What I meant by saying validation was It checks for the number availability from check.php not the user need to fill in part. Since its a dynamic form other row apart from row one doesnt get check. Please help..

Comment: So you say it should happen when you click on submit. Am i right? Check updated answer

Comment: No, it should check the availability once user input a value (onblur function to trigger check.php) without clicking any button.

Comment: So you want the validation to be done on php side and not at client side?

Comment: I want it on client side, once user keyed in their input the validation or check process runs. Im using this exercise as an example and am trying to use dynamic forms to validate. However it doesnt seem to work and i am asking for help here. http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/how-to-check-username-availability-in.html